# Stuck on how to retrieve data of the object searching by name in one array of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, vector

yes I have a problem, for days in college we were implementing the java Vector class, and now the teacher has ordered the implementation of all methods of the class, but the teacher asked us to add one more method on our own , which is used to search for a student's name and then return all data related to this student object. so that I could add students and their data I used the idea of array of objects but I can't retrieve a name and later return all data related to it. thanks for the help!

```
 //Atributs class

package Teste;


public class Aluno {

private String primeiroNome,apelido,nacionalidade,nrBI,estadoCivil;
private char sexo;
private int idade;

public Aluno(String primeiroNome){
    this.primeiroNome=primeiroNome;
}

public Aluno(String primeiroNome, String apelido, String nacionalidade, String nrBI, String estadoCivil, char sexo, int idade) {
    this.primeiroNome = primeiroNome;
    this.apelido = apelido;
    this.nacionalidade = nacionalidade;
    this.nrBI = nrBI;
    this.estadoCivil = estadoCivil;
    this.sexo = sexo;
    this.idade = idade;
}



public String getPrimeiroNome() {
    return primeiroNome;
}

public String getApelido() {
    return apelido;
}

public char getSexo() {
    return sexo;
}

public String getNacionalidade() {
    return nacionalidade;
}

public String getNrBI() {
    return nrBI;
}

public String getEstadoCivil() {
    return estadoCivil;
}

public int getIdade() {
    return idade;
}

@Override
public String toString(){  
    return "Nome: "+this.getPrimeiroNome()+"\n\n Apelido: "+this.getApelido()+"\n\nSexo: "+this.getApelido()+"\n\nNacionalidade: "+this.getNacionalidade()+"\n\nNumero de Bi: "+this.getNrBI()+"\n\nEstado Civil: "+this.getEstadoCivil()+"\n\n  idade: "+this.getIdade();
}

    }
```

public class implementation{

```
    ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();//This is the class we have implemented it works like the java vetor class

    //this is the one more method that the teacher wants

    public String retrieveData(String name){
    Aluno search= new Aluno(name);
    for(int i=0;i<lista.tamanho();i++){
    if(lista.has(new Aluno(name))){
        return search.toString(); 
    }  
   }
return null;
```

}

Comment: You keep creating new Aluno (I assume Student) objects. I think what you want to do is to get each item from lista, and then check the object's name with the name you're searching for.

Comment: It's so-so that,but after that i need to get de data related to the object i was seraching for.  .

Comment: Yes, but I'm assuming that names are unique (unlike in the real world). Once you find the object, you can use the getters and retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks for answers...but i reviewed the entire code and now it works...thanks!

Comment: And one more question is...how can i get data by filtering by sex...i get with the sex as a param and the code retrieves me all persons with that sex...??thanks